# AngularJS $q.all() not resolving in routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have an AngularJS 1.6.3 app and am having an issue with `$q.all()` not correctly resolving. It seems that the `resolve` function in my config (`sessionService.initializeApp()`) is not even getting called at all.

The `console.log()` statements are not being run, and the network requests are not being made. However, if I change `sessionService.initializeApp()` to simply be a variable instead of a function call with a return (i.e. `var initializeApp = return $q.all(...)`), and just call `sessionService.initializeApp` in the `resolve`, the network requests are made, but the `console.log()` statements do not run, and the controller does not instantiate.

I feel like I am returning the promises correctly, but obviously something is wrong since the resolve is not actually resolving. Any ideas here?

**app.config.js**

```
//more code above...
.when('/dashboard', {
    slug: 'dashboard',
    templateUrl: 'app/dashboard/dashboard.html',
    controller: 'DashboardController',
    options: {
        title: 'Dashboard'
    },
    resolve: {
        appReady: function(sessionService) {
            console.log('resolving...');
            return sessionService.initializeApp();
        }
    }
})
//more code below...
```

**session.service.js**

```
//more code above...
var state = {
    appReady: false,
    loading: false,
    data: {}
};

var service = {
    initializeApp: initializeApp,
    getData: getData,
    setData: setData
};

function initializeApp() {
    return $q.all({
        user: ajaxService.get('SupplierService.svc/me', {}),
        states: ajaxService.get('SupplierService.svc/states', {}),
        utilityTypes: ajaxService.get('SupplierService.svc/utilities/types', {}),
        roles: ajaxService.get('SupplierService.svc/contacts/types', {})
    }).then(function(response) {
        setData('user', response.user['data']);
        setData('states', response.states['data']);
        setData('utilityTypes', response.utilityTypes['data']);
        setData('roles', response.roles['data']);
    }).catch(function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }).finally(function() {
        state.appReady = true;
    });
}

function getData(key) {
    if (key) {
        return state.data[key];
    } else {
        return state.data;
    }
}

function setData(key, val) {
    state.data[key] = val;
}

return service;
//more code below...
```

**dashboard.controller.js**

```
//more code above...
function DashboardController($q, ajaxService, sessionService) {
    console.log('dashboard...');
});
//more code below...
```

Comment: Looks like your initializeApp function is missing a closing brace :)

Comment: @AJFunk - Whoops! Bad copy/paste on my end. It actually does not have a missing closing brace in the full code... I have edited my question.

Comment: What's setData? It's likely not called because you don't inject appReady into the controller.

Comment: @estus - just updated the question to show the implementation of setData() and how it is used in the service.

Comment: Did injecting appReady solved the issue? setData/getData looks like antipattern. Returning a promise is enough, especially since you're using a resolver, which unwraps a promise.

Comment: @estus - unfortunately, injecting `appReady` into the Dashboard controller didn't make any difference. I'm currently settling on calling `sessionService.initializeApp().then(...)` in every controller, but with an immediate `$q.when('appReady')` if the app is already ready so that I don't have to make duplicate server requests. Not the cleanest, but it works for now...

Comment: Well, it should either instantiate `appReady` resolver or throw an error if it can't do that for some reason. Please, provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that can replicate the problem. A plunk or something. Of course, it shouldn't be like how you're doing it now.

Answer (score 0):

catch the promise from controller instead of the service. in the service just return the `$q.all`

```
//more code above...
var service = {
    initializeApp: initializeApp
};

function initializeApp() {
    return $q.all({
        user: ajaxService.get('SupplierService.svc/me', {}),
        states: ajaxService.get('SupplierService.svc/states', {}),
        utilityTypes: ajaxService.get('SupplierService.svc/utilities/types', {}),
        roles: ajaxService.get('SupplierService.svc/contacts/types', {})
    })

}
return service;
```

catch the promise in controller

```
function DashboardController($q, ajaxService, sessionService,setData) {
    sessionService..then(function(response) {
        setData('user', response.user['data']);
        setData('states', response.states['data']);
        setData('utilityTypes', response.utilityTypes['data']);
        setData('roles', response.roles['data']);
    }).catch(function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }).finally(function() {
        state.appReady = true;
    });
});
```

Comment: This would work, but I only want to run initializeApp() once when the app first loads. Otherwise, It will make all those requests each time the user changes routes/pages.

Comment: but each time when you are calling `sessionService` from the controller it will get executed

Comment: This won't work because of how resolvers work. If a resolver rejects, the route won't be activated. And injected `sessionService` is a resolved value of a promise, not a promise itself.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I've given up on using `resolve` and just modified `sessionService.initializeApp()` to check for whether the app is ready, and if so, just return a resolved promise immediately so I don't have to refetch resources from the server.

```
function initializeApp() {
    if (isAppReady()) {
        return $q.when('appReady');
    }

    return $q.all({
        user: ajaxService.get('SupplierService.svc/me', {}),
        states: ajaxService.get('SupplierService.svc/states', {}),
        utilityTypes: ajaxService.get('SupplierService.svc/utilities/types', {}),
        roles: ajaxService.get('SupplierService.svc/contacts/types', {})
    }).then(function(response) {
        setData('user', response.user['data']);
        setData('states', response.states['data']);
        setData('utilityTypes', response.utilityTypes['data']);
        setData('roles', response.roles['data']);
    }).catch(function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }).finally(function() {
        setAppReady(true);
    });
}
```

And then in my controllers, I just do:

```
sessionService.initializeApp().then(function() {
    //do stuff
});
```